# Raster calculators in SAGA return incorrect results

Tags: qgis-2, raster-calculator, saga, qgis-processing, grids-sum

Here's a sample of my dataset (one cell) with 28 different raster values, representing 28 individual Float32 rasters with identical parameters.

```
0.0000264434,   0.0049953502,   0.0007529828,   0.0002075955,   0.0000516699972,    0.0000000000,   0.0053563155,   0.0000000000,   0.0000000000,   0.0073998945,   0.0000804775,   0.0000000000,   0.0000387653,   0.0000000000,   0.0000000000,   0.0000000000,   0.0000000000,   0.0000000000,   0.0007369027,   0.0000519922,   0.0053393530,   0.0000000000000,    0.0000000000000,    0.0000000000000,    0.0000808992875,    0.0000000000000,    0.0000000000000,    0.0000000000000,
```

Due to system overload when I run the algorithm in a modeler, I've split the process into 4 groups of 7 layers by order of appearence.
Each subgroup does the summary correct in all the calculation algorithms, including both SAGA ones: `Raster Calculator` and `Grids Sum`.
However, when I do the final summarization of the 4 rasters, It appears that the SAGA algorithms return a different result

- Excel: 0.0251186417
- GDAL_CALC: 0.0251186417
- SAGA Raster Calculator: 0.060915395617485046
- SAGA Grids Sum:0.0012134892167523503

It's worth noting that if if I run both SAGA algorithms in a standalone way on all 28 rasters, I get the correct result like excel, gdal.

I tried to look if the SAGA algorithms truncate the data somehow but it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I suspect you'd get good answers for this from the SAGA development team here: http://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/discussion/