# QGIS SAGA Raster Calculator returns incorrect results

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, saga

The SAGA Raster Calculator within QGIS produces wrong results probably due to interpolation but works corretly withion SAGA itself. The problem has been discussed here before but sofar I have not found any useful solution.
see also: 
   [Why does SAGA raster calculator interpolate between cell values?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186518/why-does-saga-raster-calculator-interpolate-between-cell-values) 
   [Raster calculators in SAGA return incorrect results](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173448/raster-calculators-in-saga-return-incorrect-results)).
Why does interpolation (?) occur and how can it be avoided? I need the raster calculation to be performed within a QGIS python script.

Comment: You should maybe check on mixed projection issues ?

Comment: Not the case. The two rasters are two different bands from the same landsat scene, so even within wrong projections there should not be any projection issue.